# Influence of the genetic and biological factors on child's gender and twins

Tags: data-request, medical, biology

I am interested in genetic factors as well as any other biological features in the parents that affect the sex of the newborn child, as well as the prevalence of twins.
Something like this format:

[image]

If there is no such data, studies about the influence of any factors on sex and twins are welcome too.